# Is the following enum validator thread safe?

Tags: java, generics, enums, bean-validation

I have implemented an enum validator following the older posts here. I was wondering whether this following code is thread safe or not? I have got many different enums for which I need to use this validator. Is this going to create any problems?

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = StringEnumerationValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NotNull(message="Value must not be null.")
public @interface StringEnumeration {

    String message() default "{com.xxx.bean.validation.constraints.StringEnumeration.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default{};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();
}


public class StringEnumerationValidator implements
    ConstraintValidator<StringEnumeration, String> {

    private Set<String> AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES;

    public static Set<String> getNamesSet(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e){
        Enum<?>[] enums = e.getEnumConstants();
        String[] names = new String[enums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < enums.length; i++) {
            names[i] = enums[i].name();
            System.out.println(enums.length);
            System.out.println(enums[i]);
        }
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
        return mySet;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(StringEnumeration stringEnumeration) {
        Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumSelected =   stringEnumeration.enumClass();
        AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES = getNamesSet(enumSelected);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
        return true;
        }
        else {
            return AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES.contains(value);
        }

  }
```

EDIT: Sources referred:

- [JSR-303 Bean Validation annotate multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804009/jsr-303-bean-validation-annotate-multiple-fields)
- [How to use Hibernate validation annotations with enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205787/how-to-use-hibernate-validation-annotations-with-enums)
- [Java String validation using enum values and annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation)

Comment: Since your `isValid` method does only reads, it is thread safe, assuming that the validation framework obeys the contract of not calling `isValid` before the completion of `initialize`.

Comment: Updated tags, fixed typos and removed thanks. Please add links to the "older posts" you are referring to.

Comment: @Ram Added the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Strictly speaking, it is not thread safe, because your `initialize` method could be called concurrently by two different threads. This method writes to the `AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES` variable, and thus the two threads might interfer with each other.

But if you make sure that `initialize` is called only once for each instance, before other threads have access to that instance, it is thread safe because `isValid` only reads the set and does not modify it.

To ensure that initializing is done only once, you should do it in the constructor:

```
public StringEnumeratorValidator(StringEnumeration stringEnumeration) {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumSelected = stringEnumeration.enumClass();
    AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES = getNamesSet(enumSelected);
}
```

and remove the `intialize` method.